# How to determine what subsystem listens to each port in a large java system

Tags: unix, networking, port

I have a big java system on unix with many subsystems (email, connection etc..) that listen on many ports, but i dont know  which of my classes\subsystems listen to which port.

Is there a tool that can help me figure this out?

example:
this is what i get when i run netstat, and i dont know what in my java system is using port 2503 and what 2505

```
>netstat -nap |grep 250
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2503     0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26659/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2505     0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26659/java
```

Answer (score 1):

The same PID/app is using 2 ports. You have your answer.

You will have to be MUCH more specific on your problem given the fact that the answer is so obvious based on the information provided; I can only assume this isn't what you're looking for

Comment: I was a bit unclear on OP's question, but my interpretation was "I have a Java app (single PID) that is using multiple ports.  Is there any way to figure out which classes are using which ports within this application?"

Comment: If that is the questioners REAL question then the answer is flatly NO!
It seems to me the questioner is an OPs guy trying to investigate a problem. Which would beg the question: What on Earth (even if you could know) would knowing the class, initiating the socket listen, do for you? Would you delete it? move it? Any Java dev will tell you that could be catastrophic to your app

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the PID, you can use ps

> ps -Af |grep 26659 |less

The -f option will show not only the program (java) that is using the port, but also the command line used to start it. So if you have multiple java processes running, and each are started as a separate task, you will see which one is using the port.

You will probably want to view the result in "less" so you can scroll the very long command lines common to java.